# Performing validation of a Business object. What about the contained objects?

Tags: .net, validation, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

I am new to Enterprise Library. I am trying to validate a Business Object of type `JuvenileClientContactItem`.

The`JuvenileClientContactItem` objects itself has contained objects, in this case, two instances of objects of `AddressType` type.

When I perform the following call to validate the `JuvenileClientContactItem`, I expected that all contained objects would also be validated and any errors encountered in the `PersonType` object would be added to the `ValidationResults` collection, but only the validations on the `JuvenileClientContactItem` oject were performed.

```
validationResults = validationService
    .Validate(Of JuvenileClientContactItem) _
    (juvenileClientContactItem, _
    "JuvenileClientContactItemRuleSet", "PersonTypeRuleSet")
```

Here's the signature of the Enterprise Library Validate function:

```
Public Shared Function Validate(Of T)(ByVal target As T, _
    ByVal ParamArray rulesets() As String) _
    As Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.ValidationResults
```

To validate the two `Address` sub objects within the `JuvenileClientContactItem` object, I need to perform separate calls to the `Validate` method, eg:

```
residentaddressValidationResults = validationService
    .Validate(Of BusinessObjects.AddressType) _
    (juvenileClientContactItem.ResidenceAddress, _
    Me.View, "AddressTypeRuleSet")
```

I am tempted to write my own generic validation method that uses reflection to examine the object passed for validation looking for contained objects that are support self validation and perform calls and aggregate the results of all validations into a single returned collection. Is there a better approach?

Edit:

Following the suggestion mentioned below, I added this code:

```
<System.Serializable()> _
<DataContract()> _
<HasSelfValidation()> _
<ObjectValidator()> _
Public Class AddressType
```

...And  got the error that the ObjectValidatorAttribute can not ba applied because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.

Why? How do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

You should decorate the properties of the `TheJuvenileClientContactItem` type with the `ObjectValidatorAttribute`, because Validation Application Block will not validate object graphs by default (to prevent performance problems and stack overflow exceptions).

Comment: Please see my edit regarding the error that I got when trying this: "ObjectValidatorAttribute can not ba applied because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type."

Comment: @Velika: You should place the attribute on the property in the `JuvenileClientContactItem` type, not on the `AddressType` itself.

Comment: @Velika: Please post the code of the `JuvenileClientContactItem` class.

Comment: @Velika: You need to remove the `ObjectValidator` attribute from `AddressType` (and JuvenileClientContactItem class if you added on there) and place the `ObjectValidator` attribute on the property or field you wish to validate.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650581.aspx#Y1140

Comment: @Vekika: Show us the complete code, to see what you're doing.